# Azure SQL: Cannot connect via JDBC from Google Sheets

Tags: azure, jdbc, google-sheets, azure-sql-database, google-sheets-api

Trying to connect to Azure SQL from Google Sheets.

This is the code i'm using:

```
  var address = 'thedb.database.windows.net';
  var user = 'myuser';
  var userPwd = 'mypassword';
  var db = 'myDB';
  var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address;
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ':1433;DatabaseName='+db;

function createDatabase() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(instanceUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE Test_table');
}
```

However, this does not work.

The error i'm getting is below:
[image: Google Sheets Error]

Azure has been configured with the IP range for Google sheets in the firewall rules:
[image: Azure firewall]

As indicated in their documents:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Yet it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the list of IP addresses is not complete. Is it a production database? If NO,  you can try to ***temporarily*** allow full access from Internet (remember that sometime rules requires a minute or more to be applied).  If your database contains real/sensitive data, you can do the same test against another DB on another Sql instance. Create it, test it and remember to destroy it  :)

Comment: It's a dev DB, however I dont think Azure allows access from everywhere?

Comment: AFAIK a rule 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 allows all connections from the Internet

Comment: I have the same problem. I added 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot rely on the IP address of an Azure SQL Database since the IP can change at any time as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/03/27/dont-rely-on-a-static-ip-address-for-your-sql-database/).

If you still have to use IP addresses to connect to Azure SQL Database then you will have to add the whole set of [Azure Datacenter IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) since and endpoint of Azure SQL Database could be located on any of those IP addresses.

Comment: The whole set of IP ranges for Google Sheets has been added, as indicated by their documentation.

Comment: Can you try opening up the entire range of IP addresses (from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the connection strings in the Azure Portal, I found out that you need to write your username in the form `<user>@<database>`. So in your case that would be `'myuser@myDB'`.

Edit:

Since the hostname of my database instance is the same as my database name, it could be that it's `'myuser@thedb'` . I'm not entirely sure. But please try ;)